# latest video by youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

In order to learn this api I am trying to create a bot.

one of the things this bot does is to first comment when a channel uploads a video.

On some channels it works however on some channels it doesn't work.

For example on this channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC295-Dw_tDNtZXFeAPAW6Aw
it claims the latest video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZI3Krk59T4 when the real latest video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pceedMMwwcE&t.

```
self.youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api, credentials=credentials)
self.upload_id = self.youtube.channels().list(id=self.channel_id, part='contentDetails').execute()['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']


def get_latest_video(self):
    url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=1&playlistId={self.upload_id}&key={self.api}'
    json_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(json_url.read())
    self.quata_spent += 3
    return data['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']
```

which is the same as calling this 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=1&playlistId={self.upload_id}&key={self.api}
Has anyone else has encountered this inconsistency ?

edit:

I found out that using the search method instead of the playlistItems works fine. Does anyone know why ? I cant afford using the search method as it costs 100 quatas per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pitfall of the API. Please consider carefully the following:

The [PlaylistItems endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) queried for the uploads list of a channel produces an [items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response) list which is ordered by [videoPublishedAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.videoPublishedAt). But the [items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) themselves contains [publishedAt](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.publishedAt) datetime properties attached. (The emphasis below is mine.)

> [**videos#snippet.publishedAt**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) (datetime)
>
> The date and time that the video was published. *Note that this time might be different than the time that the video was uploaded.* For example, if a video is uploaded as a private video and then made public at a later time, this property will specify the time that the video was made public.

Then the output obtained is fact correct:

```
$ youtube-data --channel=UC295-Dw_tDNtZXFeAPAW6Aw --uploads --page=+2 --table --relative-date|grep -wEn '^(cZI3Krk59T4|pceedMMwwcE)'
 1:cZI3Krk59T4   2   days  8  hours ago    33 LIFE-SAVING OUTDOOR TRICKS YOU NEED TO TRY YOURSELF
62:pceedMMwwcE   8  hours 19   mins ago    25 CRAZY IDEAS TO HAVE FUN WITH FRIENDS

$ youtube-data --playlist=UU295-Dw_tDNtZXFeAPAW6Aw --videos --page=+2 --table --relative-date|grep -wEn '^(cZI3Krk59T4|pceedMMwwcE)'
 1:cZI3Krk59T4   2   days  8  hours ago    33 LIFE-SAVING OUTDOOR TRICKS YOU NEED TO TRY YOURSELF
62:pceedMMwwcE   8  hours 19   mins ago    25 CRAZY IDEAS TO HAVE FUN WITH FRIENDS
```

Comment: Can you translate  your request  into  a get request ?

Comment: You may do it yourself since the shell function `youtube-data` is quite evolved (see it on my github account). Anyway, the URLs on which `wget` is called are the same as yours are (modulo using `pageToken` for pagination): ```https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=$APP_KEY&part=contentDetails,id,snippet,status&maxResults=50```

Comment: But how come this request https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UU295-Dw_tDNtZXFeAPAW6Aw%22%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22pceedMMwwcE%26t%22%7D doesn't even find the video ?

Comment: Since I am calling `youtube-data` with page being `2`  -- that is am querying the first *two* pages of the uploads playlist --, each invocation of `youtube-data` makes two HTTP requests on the PlaylistItems' `list` endpoint. The two URLs are almost identical: the second is containing the `pageToken` parameter referring to the second page: `&pageToken=CDIQAA`. Note that `CDIQAA` is received as the parameter `nextPageToken` on the first API invocation (the one corresponding to the first page).

Comment: I see, so it is not possible to fetch the latest video in one call with playlistItems in this case. Am i correct ?